# Scaled and conditionally format a sheet based on intervals collected

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a scaled log for some sample data and I am at a loss as to where to start.

I collect data like shown in image 1.

[image: Example of Collected Data]

I am attempting to create a log that looks like the second image, where cells are conditionally formatted based on their value (CLAY, SAND, GRAVEL) and it needs to scale down the page if the log is longer (i.e. for 500m in 0.1m increments).

Each row needs to be 0.1m but the data is collected in an interval (from, to).

[image]

Would someone be able to suggest a method to explore using VBA, I have experimented with an if(and( statement to colour the cells based on the interval but nested if's isn't an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly your second picture with filled cells. It seems only the gravel is painted over correctly - cells from 0.5 to 0.8, the rest are empty. According to your reference table, the silt should only be painted over in the first cell, and the sand in cells 0.1-0.5 and cells 0.8-1.1, right?

Answer (score 1):

When comparing data on multiple conditions, use the **[SUMPRODUCT()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)** function. To make the function parameters numeric rather than logical, wrap each of the conditions in an **[N()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/n-function-a624cad1-3635-4208-b54a-29733d1278c9)** function. Condition formula for conditional formatting

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(B$1=$H$2:$H$5);N($A2>$F$2:$F$5);N($A2<=$G$2:$G$5))>0
```

will do all the work (of course, all addresses in the formula must be changed to your real data - this formula uses the ranges shown in my example).

[image: CondFormatIntervals.png]

*(Answer improved after discussion in comments)*

Comment: Thanks JohnSUN, this works perfect however I can't have two formatted cells in the same row (each interval cannot be both sand and clay for example). I should have made my image a bit clearer. i.e. C2, D6 and C9 need to be unformatted.

Comment: Do you mean that the bottom size "FROM" is imprecise equality? Oh yes, you're right - particle size 0 is ridiculous! Clay is anything LARGER than 0 and less than or equal to 0.1, sand is anything LARGER than clay, and so on. Just change the comparison in the first parenthesis from `>=` to `>`

Comment: Thanks again, exactly what I am looking for, although that formula doesn't seem to work. I've modified it for mine but it gives me an error. =SUMPRODUCT(N(B$1=$R$3:$R$999);N($A3>$P$3:$P$999);N($A2<=$Q$3:$Q$999))>0

Comment: Looks like the correct formula. Only in one place is $A**3**, and in another $A**2** - make them the same and see the result